# how to read csv header or first row of csv in upload in php?

Tags: php, csv

Not able to read CSV header or the first row of CSV in PHP. The reading starts from second row. How can I read header in CSV upload in PHP?

Comment: share code, what you have written.Than only we are able to correct/upgrade it.

Comment: `for ($line=0` and not `for ($line=1` ? :)

Comment: Reading starts from the first row unless your code says to skip it. Show us what you have and we can show you how to fix it